# Facebook iOS SDK 4.6 still ask for facebook login by safari even already login in device settings->facebook

Tags: facebook-login, ios9

I'm using Facebook SDK 4.6 and compile my iOS app with XCode7beta5. The app will use Facebook account details to signin our iOS app. However, even already login in device settings->facebook. The login api in Facebook SDK still ask for facebook login by safari (happen in iOS8.4.1 or iOS9beta5 once my iOS app using Facebook SDK 4.6 compile with XCode7beta5). My previous iOS app version that using an older Facebook SDK version could work properly (i.e. able to use login in device settings->facebook)
Besides, I already follow steps in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9 to setup my iOS app to use Facebook SDK 4.6.
Anything I missed? Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32338007/facebook-sdk-4-6-login-button-on-ios-doesnt-use-facebook-app-for-authentication seemed to answer the question

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer:
[Facebook Login does not return to App with Xcode 7 iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32567179/facebook-login-does-not-return-to-app-with-xcode-7-ios-9)

It seems that in SDK 4.6 Facebook prefer to open Safari View Controller by default than the Facebook App...

Comment: That is correct - in SDK v4.6 and v.3.24, Safari View Controller is used as the default Facebook Login flow - testing and research has shown this to be the best experience for people, and the most effective for developers.