# Facebook Login does not return to App with Xcode 7 iOS 9

Tags: facebook-login, appdelegate, ios9, xcode7

I have implemented this method for Facebook Login in the App Delegate using Xcode 7 and it works perfectly:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString*, id> *)options {

return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:app
                                                      openURL:url
                                            sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                                   annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
}
```

However, since I need to use Xcode 6 to submit my app to the App Store, this method does not exists and it give me errors.

If I comment the above method, and leave only the following:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                      openURL:url
                                            sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                   annotation:annotation
        ];


}
```

it will not work, that is, when the user tries to Login, it does not return to the Application.

Is there an easy fix for this? Thanks!

BTW, I have followed diligently all steps in : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems there's no way to get the previous behavior using newests FB SDKs in iOS9. You can use a old SDK to do that. Here's a response from the facebook to that question:

[image]

Comment: Is it just me or the interstitial dialog only appears once when done via app switch? Because if that's the case users won't mind having to pass through that. The app switch is still the way to go.

Comment: @Teffi It appears only once but I believe good number of users will mind to that.

Comment: @Teffi - the dialog appears twice for each app - once when going from the app to FB, once on the return journey. As people tend to login to an app only once - these double-dialogs will appear EVERY time someone tries to log into a new app.

With Safari View Controller, once you're signed into Safari, every time you log into a new app you have a fast and easy experience. This is why Safari View Controller ultimately performs better over time than the fast-app-switch flow.

Comment: @SimonCross Thanks for clarifying. I just find it quite uncomfortable to keep my facebook login in two platforms (1) FB app (2) Safari. Well that's might just be me.

Comment: @SimonCross I just tried on my app again using old FB SDK on iOS9. The app switching appears to be seamless to me. I didn't came across some dialog boxes (1)Login via Facebook (2)App switch to FB (3) Login my account /enable permission (4) FB app switches back to my app. (5) my App now opened. no dialog box appearing like you've mentioned.

Comment: @Teffi - the interstitials appear once for every app-pair - this means the first time you login to your app, you'll see them in both directions, but not if you repeat the process. This gives you, the developer, the sense that this flow is low friction. But this isn't a realistic scenario. Most people login to an app once or twice - thus they'll see these interstitials for every new app they log into - it quickly become fatiguing. Its worth remembering that your experience testing Login for a single app is very atypical.

Comment: @SimonCross, so which way is it? Does the end user see the interstitials once or multiple times? I just tested this and as a new user, yes I have to approve opening FB native app and then approve whatever that app wants to access. But if I logout from that mobile app and login again I don't have to do that. Not even if I delete the app from my phone. But if I use the new SDK with SafariViewController, I have to possibly log into FB, approve FB app to access whatever. If I logout, on the way in I have to possibly login again and I always see "You have already authorised this app" screen.